# Nuxeo server upload multiple files to a document

Tags: rest, file-upload, nuxeo, nuxeo-js-client

Using below endpoint I can create document with single file in nuxeo server : 
http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/api/v1/path/domain/workspace.
But I can not create document with multiple files. How I can do it?

Comment: how did you upload single file?

Comment: @Dipes https://doc.nuxeo.com/nxdoc/howto-upload-file-nuxeo-using-rest-api/

Answer (score 1):

```
http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/api/v1/upload/
```

gives you `<myBatchId>`

**Posting first image on that batch**

```
http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/api/v1/upload/<myBatchId>/0
```

**Posting second image on that batch**

```
http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/api/v1/upload/<myBatchId>/1
```

**Posting third image on that batch**

```
http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/api/v1/upload/<myBatchId>/2
```

**Finally**

```
http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/api/v1/path/domain/workspace

{
  "entity-type": "document",
  "name":"myNewDoc",
  "type": "File",
  "properties" : {
    "dc:title":"My new doc",
    "file:content": {
      "upload-batch":"<myBatchId>",
      "upload-fileId":"0"
    },
    "files:files":[
        { "file" :  {
           "upload-batch":"<myBatchId>",
           "upload-fileId":"1"
        }},
        { "file" :  {
           "upload-batch":"<myBatchId>",
           "upload-fileId":"2"
        }},
     ]
   }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: cant see file in folder or download

Comment: Can you see your one file that you uploaded? Show what you did in more detail